# How to ensure WebSocket send notifications to certain connected clients in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, websocket, chat

Let's say I am building a chat app, and it needs to support switching channel feature. I have two users in channel 1 chatting and other 2 users in channel 2 chatting. Clients are getting updated via WebSocket.

The problem is that users in channel 1 also get Websocket notifications when other users are chatting on channel 2, because WebSocket broadcasts notifications to all connected clients. How can I ensure my WebSocket only broadcasts to connected clients on a given channel?

The solution I am currently using right now is to filter Websocket notifications on client-side (I can do so because each notification message has a channel Id), but this is not the best way to solve this problem.

I am using **ws npm** package for my **Node.js** server-side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use an abstraction like [socket.io](https://socket.io) which handles channel separation more formally. What you need is a proper pub-sub model.

Comment: @tadman Thanks! I was actually thinking about that. But the current codebase is using `ws` package. So there is no way to handle channel separation with native WebSocket?

Comment: There is but you'll end up building your own version of socket.io as you need to write both server fan-out code, the publish part, and the client, the subscriber part. It's probably easier to just swap one package for another since they're both JavaScript anyway.

Comment: @tadman Got it! Thanks a lot